# What is the difference between allocation unit size and sector size?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, formatting, sectors, allocation-unit

I have been given the following disk recommendation:

> The disk drives should have standard native **sector size**s of 512
> bytes and 4 KB. Hard disks with sector sizes larger than 4 KB may
> cause errors when attempting to store application data.
>
> The **allocation unit size** must be configured to 64K when formatting
> the disk.

What is the difference between allocation unit size and sector size?

Answer (score 1):

The **allocation unit size** is a term of the file system (operating system software) , the sector size is a term of the underlying hardware.

File systems do not necessarily use single sectors to manage drive space.
Sometimes they combine single physical sectors into a logical administration unit. The size of such a bunch of sectors is called "allocation unit size".

When formating a partition you typically have the choice to set the "allocation unit size" (cluster size in Microsoft operating systems).

A common combination in the NTFS (Microsoft file system, used in Windows operating systems) is to combine 8 sectors with a size of 512 byte into a so-called "cluster". Cluster seems to be the Microsoft equivalent of the more generalized term "allocation unit size". This cluster size of 4096 byte is the minimum increment/decrement when occupying/releasing storage space.